# OSX: FFT Analysis AudioUnit

Tags: macos, fft, audiounit

i am interested in FFT analysis for mac osx. I have found an tutorial for iOS (http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/) and tried to "port" it to OSX.

I have created a new Xcode-Project, integrated the code and removed the visible bugs. Although is does not work :(

I tried many modifications about the AudioUnit part, but it does not help.

**Has anybody an idea what is wrong?
Thank you very much :)**

myView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class RIOInterface;

@interface myView : NSView {


BOOL isListening;
RIOInterface *rioRef;

NSMutableString *key;
float currentFrequency;
NSString *prevChar;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *key;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *prevChar;
@property(readwrite) RIOInterface *rioRef;
@property(nonatomic, assign) float currentFrequency;
@property(assign) BOOL isListening;


#pragma mark Listener Controls
- (IBAction)toggleListening:(id)sender;
- (void)startListener;
- (void)stopListener;

- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency;
- (void)updateFrequencyLabel;

@end
```

myView.m

```
#import "myView.h"
#import "RIOInterface.h"


@implementation myView
@synthesize key;
@synthesize prevChar;
@synthesize isListening;
@synthesize rioRef;
@synthesize currentFrequency;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Listener Controls
- (void)toggleListening {
if (isListening) {
    [self stopListener];
} else {
    [self startListener];
}

isListening = !isListening;
}

- (void)startListener {
[rioRef startListening:self];
}

- (void)stopListener {
[rioRef stopListening];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
rioRef = [RIOInterface sharedInstance];
[self toggleListening];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {

    [self viewDidLoad];
}

return self;
}



@end
```

RIOInterface.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

@class myView;

/**
 *  This is a singleton class that manages all the low level CoreAudio/RemoteIO
 *  elements. A singleton is used since we should never be instantiating more
 *  than one instance of this class per application lifecycle.
 */

#define kInputBus 1
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kBufferSize 1024
#define kBufferCount 1
#define N 10


@interface RIOInterface : NSObject {
NSView *selectedViewController;
myView *listener;

AUGraph processingGraph;
AudioUnit ioUnit;
AudioBufferList* bufferList;
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;

FFTSetup fftSetup;
COMPLEX_SPLIT A;
int log2n, n, nOver2;

void *dataBuffer;
float *outputBuffer;
size_t bufferCapacity;  // In samples
size_t index;   // In samples

float sampleRate;
float frequency;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> audioPlayerDelegate;
@property(readwrite) myView *listener;

@property(assign) float sampleRate;
@property(assign) float frequency;

#pragma mark Lifecycle

#pragma mark Audio Session/Graph Setup
- (void)initializeAudioSession;
- (void)createAUProcessingGraph;
- (size_t)ASBDForSoundMode;

#pragma mark Playback Controls
- (void)startPlayback;
- (void)startPlaybackFromEncodedArray:(NSArray *)encodedArray;
- (void)stopPlayback;
- (void)printASBD:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)asbd;

#pragma mark Listener Controls
- (void)startListening:(myView*)aListener;
- (void)stopListening;

#pragma mark Generic Audio Controls
- (void)initializeAndStartProcessingGraph;
- (void)stopProcessingGraph;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (RIOInterface *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

RIOInterface.m

```
#import "RIOInterface.h"
#import "CAStreamBasicDescription.h"
#import "CAXException.h"
#import "myView.h"

@implementation RIOInterface

@synthesize listener;
@synthesize audioPlayerDelegate;
@synthesize sampleRate;
@synthesize frequency;

float MagnitudeSquared(float x, float y);
void ConvertInt16ToFloat(RIOInterface* THIS, void *buf, float *outputBuf, size_t capacity);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle

- (void)dealloc {
if (processingGraph) {
    AUGraphStop(processingGraph);
}



}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Playback Controls
- (void)startPlayback {
[self createAUProcessingGraph];
[self initializeAndStartProcessingGraph];
//AudioOutputUnitStart(ioUnit);
}


- (void)startPlaybackFromEncodedArray:(NSArray *)encodedArray {
// TODO: once we have our generated array, set up the timer to
// play the encoded array correctly.
}

- (void)stopPlayback {
AUGraphStop(processingGraph);
//AudioOutputUnitStop(ioUnit);
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Listener Controls
- (void)startListening:(myView*)aListener {
self.listener = aListener;
[self createAUProcessingGraph];
[self initializeAndStartProcessingGraph];
}


- (void)stopListening {
[self stopProcessingGraph];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Generic Audio Controls
- (void)initializeAndStartProcessingGraph {
OSStatus result = AUGraphInitialize(processingGraph);
if (result >= 0) {
    AUGraphStart(processingGraph);
} else {
    XThrow(result, "error initializing processing graph");
}
}

- (void)stopProcessingGraph {
AUGraphStop(processingGraph);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio Rendering
OSStatus RenderFFTCallback (void                    *inRefCon,
                        AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp            *inTimeStamp,
                        UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                        UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                        AudioBufferList             *ioData)
{
RIOInterface* THIS = (__bridge RIOInterface *)inRefCon;
COMPLEX_SPLIT A = THIS->A;
void *dataBuffer = THIS->dataBuffer;
float *outputBuffer = THIS->outputBuffer;
FFTSetup fftSetup = THIS->fftSetup;

uint32_t log2n = THIS->log2n;
uint32_t n = THIS->n;
uint32_t nOver2 = THIS->nOver2;
uint32_t stride = 1;
int bufferCapacity = THIS->bufferCapacity;
SInt16 index = THIS->index;

AudioUnit rioUnit = THIS->ioUnit;
OSStatus renderErr;
UInt32 bus1 = 1;

renderErr = AudioUnitRender(rioUnit, ioActionFlags,
                            inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, THIS->bufferList);
if (renderErr < 0) {
    return renderErr;
}

// Fill the buffer with our sampled data. If we fill our buffer, run the
// fft.
int read = bufferCapacity - index;
if (read > inNumberFrames) {
    memcpy((SInt16 *)dataBuffer + index, THIS->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16));
    THIS->index += inNumberFrames;
} else {
    // If we enter this conditional, our buffer will be filled and we should
    // perform the FFT.
    memcpy((SInt16 *)dataBuffer + index, THIS->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, read*sizeof(SInt16));

    // Reset the index.
    THIS->index = 0;

    /*************** FFT ***************/
    // We want to deal with only floating point values here.
    ConvertInt16ToFloat(THIS, dataBuffer, outputBuffer, bufferCapacity);

    /**
     Look at the real signal as an interleaved complex vector by casting it.
     Then call the transformation function vDSP_ctoz to get a split complex
     vector, which for a real signal, divides into an even-odd configuration.
     */
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)outputBuffer, 2, &A, 1, nOver2);

    // Carry out a Forward FFT transform.
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &A, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

    // The output signal is now in a split real form. Use the vDSP_ztoc to get
    // a split real vector.
    vDSP_ztoc(&A, 1, (COMPLEX *)outputBuffer, 2, nOver2);

    // Determine the dominant frequency by taking the magnitude squared and
    // saving the bin which it resides in.
    float dominantFrequency = 0;
    int bin = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i+=2) {
        float curFreq = MagnitudeSquared(outputBuffer[i], outputBuffer[i+1]);
        if (curFreq > dominantFrequency) {
            dominantFrequency = curFreq;
            bin = (i+1)/2;
        }
    }
    memset(outputBuffer, 0, n*sizeof(SInt16));


    printf("Dominant frequency: %f   bin: %d \n", bin*(THIS->sampleRate/bufferCapacity), bin);
}

NSLog(@"hh");
return noErr;
}

float MagnitudeSquared(float x, float y) {
return ((x*x) + (y*y));
}

void ConvertInt16ToFloat(RIOInterface* THIS, void *buf, float *outputBuf, size_t capacity) {
AudioConverterRef converter;
OSStatus err;

size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof(float);
AudioStreamBasicDescription outFormat = {0};
outFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
outFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
outFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * bytesPerSample;
outFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
outFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
outFormat.mBytesPerPacket = bytesPerSample * outFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
outFormat.mBytesPerFrame = bytesPerSample * outFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
outFormat.mSampleRate = THIS->sampleRate;

const AudioStreamBasicDescription inFormat = THIS->streamFormat;

UInt32 inSize = capacity*sizeof(SInt16);
UInt32 outSize = capacity*sizeof(float);
err = AudioConverterNew(&inFormat, &outFormat, &converter);
err = AudioConverterConvertBuffer(converter, inSize, buf, &outSize, outputBuf);
}

/* Setup our FFT */
- (void)realFFTSetup {
UInt32 maxFrames = 2048;
dataBuffer = (void*)malloc(maxFrames * sizeof(SInt16));
outputBuffer = (float*)malloc(maxFrames *sizeof(float));
log2n = log2f(maxFrames);
n = 1 << log2n;
assert(n == maxFrames);
nOver2 = maxFrames/2;
bufferCapacity = maxFrames;
index = 0;
A.realp = (float *)malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(float));
A.imagp = (float *)malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(float));
fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFT_RADIX2);
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio Session/Graph Setup
// Sets up the audio session based on the properties that were set in the init
// method.
- (void)initializeAudioSession {
NSError *err = nil;
    // After activation, update our sample rate. We need to update because there
// is a possibility the system cannot grant our request.

[self realFFTSetup];
}


// This method will create an AUGraph for either input or output.
// Our application will never perform both operations simultaneously.
- (void)createAUProcessingGraph {
OSStatus err;
// Configure the search parameters to find the default playback output unit
// (called the kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO on iOS but
// kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput on Mac OS X)
AudioComponentDescription ioUnitDescription;
ioUnitDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
ioUnitDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
ioUnitDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
ioUnitDescription.componentFlags = 0;
ioUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

// Declare and instantiate an audio processing graph
NewAUGraph(&processingGraph);

// Add an audio unit node to the graph, then instantiate the audio unit.
/*
 An AUNode is an opaque type that represents an audio unit in the context
 of an audio processing graph. You receive a reference to the new audio unit
 instance, in the ioUnit parameter, on output of the AUGraphNodeInfo
 function call.
 */
AUNode ioNode;
AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &ioUnitDescription, &ioNode);

AUGraphOpen(processingGraph); // indirectly performs audio unit instantiation

// Obtain a reference to the newly-instantiated I/O unit. Each Audio Unit
// requires its own configuration.
AUGraphNodeInfo(processingGraph, ioNode, NULL, &ioUnit);

// Initialize below.
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct = {0};
UInt32 enableInput;
UInt32 enableOutput;

// Enable input and disable output.
enableInput = 1; enableOutput = 0;
callbackStruct.inputProc = RenderFFTCallback;

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                           kInputBus, &enableInput,     sizeof(enableInput));

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                           kOutputBus, &enableOutput, sizeof(enableOutput));

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                           kOutputBus, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct));


// Set the stream format.
size_t bytesPerSample = [self ASBDForSoundMode];

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                           kInputBus, &streamFormat, sizeof(streamFormat));

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                           kOutputBus, &streamFormat, sizeof(streamFormat));




// Disable system buffer allocation. We'll do it ourselves.
UInt32 flag = 0;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                           kInputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));


// Allocate AudioBuffers for use when listening.
// TODO: Move into initialization...should only be required once.
bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBuffer));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;

bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = kBufferSize*bytesPerSample;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = calloc(kBufferSize, bytesPerSample);
}


// Set the AudioStreamBasicDescription for listening to audio data. Set the
// stream member var here as well.
- (size_t)ASBDForSoundMode {
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd = {0};
size_t bytesPerSample;
bytesPerSample = sizeof(SInt16);
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * bytesPerSample;
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = bytesPerSample * asbd.mFramesPerPacket;
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = bytesPerSample * asbd.mChannelsPerFrame;
asbd.mSampleRate = sampleRate;

streamFormat = asbd;
[self printASBD:streamFormat];

return bytesPerSample;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Utility
- (void)printASBD:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)asbd {

char formatIDString[5];
UInt32 formatID = CFSwapInt32HostToBig (asbd.mFormatID);
bcopy (&formatID, formatIDString, 4);
formatIDString[4] = '\0';

NSLog (@"  Sample Rate:         %10.0f",  asbd.mSampleRate);
NSLog (@"  Format ID:           %10s",    formatIDString);
NSLog (@"  Format Flags:        %10lX",    asbd.mFormatFlags);
NSLog (@"  Bytes per Packet:    %10ld",    asbd.mBytesPerPacket);
NSLog (@"  Frames per Packet:   %10ld",    asbd.mFramesPerPacket);
NSLog (@"  Bytes per Frame:     %10ld",    asbd.mBytesPerFrame);
NSLog (@"  Channels per Frame:  %10ld",    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame);
NSLog (@"  Bits per Channel:    %10ld",    asbd.mBitsPerChannel);
}



// *************** Singleton *********************

static RIOInterface *sharedInstance = nil;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (RIOInterface *)sharedInstance
{
if (sharedInstance == nil) {
    sharedInstance = [[RIOInterface alloc] init];
}

return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return sharedInstance;  // assignment and return on first allocation
    }
}
return nil; // on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput on a Mac for microphone input.

Comment: what should i use instead of it?

Answer (score 0):

-for audio unit sub type try

kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput

yet, unless you really know how to port iOS audio apps to OSX, I would suggest to break the ice by porting a much simpler proces than fft (such as play-through), then use the learned hands-on experience in more demanding scenarios. It has issues way too complex to fit into a mail reply. The learning curve is steep, there in no short way of understanding how things work. Be patient, it's not a quick fix job.

On the other hand, if you'd like to examine a working example of FFT on a Mac, perhaps you might also take a look at this:

https://github.com/Sample-Hold/SimpleSpectrumAnalyzer

UU